# How can I see the Bitmap class component

Tags: c#, visual-studio

can I see the code of a   library  in c#  from the visual studio 
like Bitmap class I need the source code of it .

Comment: There is not much to see, Bitmap is just a wrapper for a big chunk of unmanaged code in gdiplus.dll.  You'd have to work for Microsoft to get access to its source code.  After 20 years of maintenance, you wouldn't *want* to see it.

Comment: _After 20 years of maintenance, you wouldn't want to see it_ LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) contains the (available) reference source for a lot of Microsoft's .NET libraries.

[Here is the source for System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e1ba6ce9c451889d)